# wireshark - tcp_dissect_pdus() sometimes doesn't work

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm wrote a wireshark dissector named PLUGIN.

Now when I'm testing it, for some reason a packet of type X can be seen on the wireshark as PLUGIN (like it should), and some other packets afterwards, of the same type X cannot be seen as PLUGIN.

The other packets can be found in the .pcap as `[TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]`

The question is: why doesn't WireShark dissect other packets of type X like the first packet of type X and shows it to me as PLUGIN ?

Why does the dissection works only for the first time?

I use functions for assembling fragments of chopped packets:

```
tcp_dissect_pdus()
get_PLUGIN_message_len()
```

as written in "9.4.2. How to reassemble split TCP Packets"

in "`http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChDissectReassemble.html#TcpDissectPdus`"

**This is the function of dissection:**
(FRAME_HEADER_LEN = 8)

```
static void
dissect_PROTOC(tvbuff_t *tvb, packet_info *pinfo, proto_tree *tree)
{
    //Reassembling TCP fragments
    tcp_dissect_pdus(tvb, pinfo, tree, TRUE, FRAME_HEADER_LEN,
                     get_PROTOC_message_len, dissect_PROTOC_message);

}

static guint get_PROTOC_message_len(packet_info *pinfo, tvbuff_t *tvb, int offset)
{
    /* the packet's size is "length" + 4bytes of TYPESIZE + 4bytes of LENGTHSIZE + 256bytes of CONTEXTIDSIZE */
    return (guint)(tvb_get_ntohl(tvb, offset + 4) + CONTEXT_ID_SIZE + TYPE_SIZE + LENGTH_SIZE); /* e.g. length is at offset 4 */
}

static void dissect_PROTOC_message(tvbuff_t *tvb, packet_info *pinfo, proto_tree *tree)
{
    /* my dissecting code */
    guint32 packet_type = tvb_get_ntohl(tvb, 0);

    col_set_str(pinfo->cinfo, COL_PROTOCOL, "PROTOC");
    /* Clear out stuff in the info column */
    col_clear(pinfo->cinfo,COL_INFO);
    col_add_fstr(pinfo->cinfo, COL_INFO, "%d > %d [%s]",pinfo->srcport, pinfo->destport,
             val_to_str(packet_type, packettypenames, "Unknown (0x%02x)"));

    if (tree) { /* we are being asked for details */
        proto_item *ti              = NULL;
        proto_tree *PROTOC_tree         = NULL;
        proto_item *PROTOC_data         = NULL;
        proto_tree *PROTOC_data_tree    = NULL;
        guint32 type    = 0;
        guint32 length  = 0;
        gint offset     = 0;

        ti = proto_tree_add_item(tree, proto_PROTOC, tvb, 0, -1, ENC_NA);
        proto_item_append_text(ti, ", Type: %s",
            val_to_str(packet_type, packettypenames, "Unknown (0x%02x)"));
        PROTOC_tree = proto_item_add_subtree(ti, ett_PROTOC);

        //getting type
        type = tvb_get_ntohl(tvb, offset);
        proto_tree_add_item(PROTOC_tree, hf_PROTOC_pdu_type, tvb, 0, TYPE_SIZE, ENC_BIG_ENDIAN);
        offset += TYPE_SIZE;

        //getting length for the data length
        length = tvb_get_ntohl(tvb, offset);
        proto_tree_add_item(PROTOC_tree, hf_PROTOC_len, tvb, offset, LENGTH_SIZE, ENC_BIG_ENDIAN);
        offset += LENGTH_SIZE;
        proto_tree_add_item(PROTOC_tree, hf_PROTOC_contextid, tvb, offset, CONTEXT_ID_SIZE, ENC_BIG_ENDIAN);
        offset += CONTEXT_ID_SIZE;
        PROTOC_data = proto_tree_add_item(PROTOC_tree, hf_PROTOC_data, tvb, offset, length, FALSE);
        PROTOC_data_tree = proto_item_add_subtree(PROTOC_data, ett_PROTOC_data);
        offset += length;

    }
}
```

more information:

1. I opened the file.pcap on some hex editor and I can see my packets that the wireshark doesn't dissect...
2. Inside wireshark I can find a packet that wireshark doesn't dissect, with the info of: "[TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]", but it doesn't say to which reassemble packet it belong, and I can't find it anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

I would speculate that your calculated length does not match the reality. If wireshark does not think it has all the frames it needs to complete the PDU, then I guess it might not call `dissect_PROTOC_message()`

You could try to print your calculated lengths and then verify that the pcap file contains that many frames:

```
static guint get_PROTOC_message_len(packet_info *pinfo, tvbuff_t *tvb, int offset)
{
    /* the packet's size is "length" + 4bytes of TYPESIZE + 4bytes of LENGTHSIZE + 256bytes of CONTEXTIDSIZE */
    guint len = (guint)(tvb_get_ntohl(tvb, offset + 4) + CONTEXT_ID_SIZE + TYPE_SIZE + LENGTH_SIZE); /* e.g. length is at offset 4 */
    g_warning("frame=%d PDU len=%d", pinfo->fd->num, len);
    return len;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I checked a lot of times the calculated length, and it seems fine... I don't know what can be wrong there, isn't the calculated length should be: the size of the whole packet ?


I did what you told with the `g_warning()`, but it works only for dissected packets, and I want to see why the packets that are not dissected - not being dissected...

Do you have any other suggestions? or inform me where I'm wrong?
Thanks..

Comment: Just to clarify: You have many TCP frames and want them reassembled into, say, three PDUs, lets call them A, B and C. You expect the following output:

Comment: If you expect [this output](https://gist.github.com/martinhansdk/5057112), but get [this instead](https://gist.github.com/martinhansdk/5057124), then I would try to put `g_warning()` calls in `dissect_PROTOC_message()` as well to check id execution even makes it here for packet C. Maybe it arrives here, but throws an exception.

Comment: That's exactly what I expect seeing, and I get the other thing instead.

I put `g_warning()` `inside the dissect_PROTOC_message()`, it seems fine.. and of course, it doesn't work for non PROTOC messages...

What do you mean by _to check id execution_ ? , maybe I didn't relate to that...

Comment: That is a typo. I meant "check if execution even makes it here". Does it? Does it also make it all the way to the end of your dissector?

Comment: But that is correct then, isn't it? Isn't it only supposed to enter `dissect_PROTOC_message()` for PROTOC packets?

Comment: Yes, but I can't test the other messages that suppose to be dissected, Like in your example... I can't see what happened to `PDU C`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25340/discussion-between-martinhans-and-hudac)

Comment: I have a little problem compiling your plugin. Can you send me instructions to do so?

Comment: I just sent it to the last email you gave me, Please tell when you got that, thanks!

Comment: Is there any way you checked it?
Thanks